# Install OpenGL ES documentation into Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es

It would be so convenient to be able to lookup gl... functions either in intelligence or "Quick Help" when developing with OpenGL ES API.

Is it possible to prepare DocSet for OpenGl ES and install it into Xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but nobody has done it yet.

Take a look at the [document set documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/Documentation_Sets/020-Creating_Documentation_Sets/creating_docsets.html) to get an idea of how to build such a thing. If you decide to work on it, please let me know :)

I submitted a bug to apple (rdar://12674421) which you should dup if you care about this issue.

Comment: Count my vote. It would be great to have docs for both OpenGL ES 2.2+ and OpenGL 3.2+.